# Combine between Drupal core search & custom view term search

Tags: search, drupal, drupal-7, full-text-search

I need to build search form was search in node or taxonomy term,

to search in node .. I can use core search module, but i cant do that for  taxonomy term, 
so, to I can search on taxonomy term, I must be create custom search .. so Im build custom search dependence of search API, and view ...

So now when i search by exposed filter from view, its will be retrieve only from taxonomy term, and if I use default search its will be retrieve only node without term field ..

How I can combine between search node & custom search ..

look to image:

[image: Node search with max value]

[image: Term Search with max value]

I need when I try to search about max, retrieval a result from both pages node & term,

or any suggestion for solve this problem .. thanks

**I found a nice solution, you can use this module 
[Multi Indexing module](https://drupal.org/project/search_api_multi)
read this too, [Here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/42697/how-to-have-a-combined-search-view-that-shows-both-users-and-content-on-search-t)
Good luck all,**

Answer (score 1):

Look at this: (combine between modules to search at node & terms)

https://drupal.org/project/search_api_multi

Comment: thats what I found ^^